# 'string' file not found on ios plugin with C++ file

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, string

I am trying running c++ file on plugin IOS (not ios app). First I create cpp file

Greeting.cpp

```
#include "Greeting.hpp"

Greeting::Greeting() {
    greeting = "Hello C++!";
}

std::string Greeting::greet() {
    return greeting;
}
```

Then I create `Greeting.hpp`

```
#ifndef Greeting_hpp
#define Greeting_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

class Greeting {
    std::string greeting;
public:
    Greeting();
    std::string greet();
};
#endif /* Greeting_hpp */
```

Then I import it into object c file 
`AgoraRtcEnginePlugin.m`

```
#import "Greeting.hpp"

NSString* newTitle = [NSString stringWithCString:greeting.greet().c_str() encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
        result(newTitle);
```

But when I complile It always throws errors

```
/agora-flutter-sdk/ios/Classes/Greeting.hpp:13:10: fatal error: 'string' file not found
#include <string>
```

Comment: Is this Objective-C or Objective-C++?

Comment: It's Objective-C - OP mentioned the file `AgoraRtcEnginePlugin.m`. `.m` = Objective-C.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling C++ from Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229574/calling-c-from-objective-c)

Comment: you need .mm file

Comment: If I create `.mm` file, How can I use it on `.m` file

Comment: Just rename all `.m` to `.mm` where you have issues

Comment: I can rename .m file because it is main file for plugin. I need call a class in `.mm` file to run on `.m` file

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that you're including C++ in your Objective-C (`AgoraRtcEnginePlugin.m` = `.m` extension is Objective-C) file. Objective-C is a layer on top of C and Objective-C is a *strict superset* of C.

You can't do this unless you use `extern "C"`, etc. There are questions about this:

- [How to call C++ function from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744181/how-to-call-c-function-from-c)
- [Calling “C++” class member function from “C” code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583353/calling-c-class-member-function-from-c-code)
- etc.

You're not forced to create an C API for you class, because there's also Objective-C++ (`.mm` extension) and you can use C++ directly in these files.

Comment: If I create `.mm` file, how can I call it on `.m` file ?